# Facing performance and scalability issues while running background schedulers in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

We've migrated from a monolithic architecture to a microservices architecture using Spring Boot cloud tools. Each customer is treated as a separate tenant with their own database. We need to continue running background activities such as data processing and sending notifications across all databases.

Considering this tenant-based architecture, what are the recommended technical approaches and best practices for efficiently implementing and managing background activities in Spring Boot microservices?

Currently, i'm running the quartz scheduler with servlet based spring boot application which is not scalable so, looking for something which provides better performance as well as scalability.

I'm having following approches in my mind but, not sure which one is the best way to go with:
-Spring Boot Servlet Application with Quartz Scheduler
-Spring Boot Console Application with Timers

Thank you for your expertise and insights!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.